# How should my compound predicate be structured to be inclusive

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I'm building a filter for my task list in my application and when I try to combine all filters I see no data.

The expected outcome is that if I were to select all filters I would see my entire data set.

Below is a simplified version of the filter -- the issue is illustrated by selecting both complete and incomplete task statuses.

```
2015-06-29 14:33:49.611 TasksApp[32174:1144416] ADD FILTER FOR INCOMPLETE TASKS
2015-06-29 14:33:49.612 TasksApp[32174:1144416] ADD FILTER FOR COMPLETE TASKS
2015-06-29 14:33:49.613 TasksApp[32174:1144416] TEMP ARRAY COUNT: 5
2015-06-29 14:33:49.613 TasksApp[32174:1144416] LOCAL RESULTS FILTERED:     (
)
```

I'm creating and adding the compound filter using the following code:

```
if ([[[defaults dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys] containsObject:@"myTasksIncomplete"]) {
    if([defaults boolForKey:@"myTasksIncomplete"]){
        NSLog(@"ADD FILTER FOR INCOMPLETE TASKS");
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(Status == %@)", @"Incomplete"];
        [predicatesArray addObject:predicate];
    }
}

if ([[[defaults dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys] containsObject:@"myTasksComplete"]) {
    if([defaults boolForKey:@"myTasksComplete"]){
        NSLog(@"ADD FILTER FOR COMPLETE TASKS");
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(Status == %@)", @"Complete"];
        [predicatesArray addObject:predicate];
    }
}

if ([[[defaults dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys] containsObject:@"myTasksToday"]) {
    if([defaults boolForKey:@"myTasksToday"]){
        //not setup yet
    }
}


//All of the predicates
NSLog(@"TEMP ARRAY COUNT: %li", [tempArray count]);
NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicatesArray];
self.localResults = [[tempArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:compoundPredicate] mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"LOCAL RESULTS FILTERED: %@", self.localResults);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you make the `NSCompoundPredicate` using `+[NSCompioundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:]`, it will *only* pass items that pass *every* subpredicate. You probably want `+[NSCompioundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:]`, which will pass items that pass *any* subpredicate.